# How to make android device FileSystem ReadOnly and ReadWrite?

Tags: android, filesystems, readonly, mount, read-write

How to make android device's file system in ReadOnly mode. i.e. currently my android box's file system `(/data, /system, /cache etc)` has ReadWrite access. I want to make it ReadOnly for some testing purpose. Also wants to know about again making it ReadWrite from ReadOnly mode.

I had tried `adb shell mount -o ro, remount /data` to make /data partition ReadOnly, but it is not working.

Any help about this will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.